# Can I use multiple titles in the title field of KeePass?

Tags: keepass

I have multiple login field with different tab titles on the same page e.g. oneplus main page and oneplus claim page using same login data but different titles.

Hiw can I use multiple titles in the the title field?

e.g. "Claim" & "Never settle*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you edit your entry and go to the Auto-Type tab you can add several window titles that is used for Auto-Type. That way you can have several window titles.

[image]

Comment: thnks for your reply that is what I was looking for

Comment: @AlexanderFedtke you should accept answer https://superuser.com/help/someone-answers